# Mediafire API get OTD direct links

Tags: hyperlink, mediafire

Does anybody know if Mediafire can generate, using its API, an One Time Download direct link?

I know it can generate a direct link AND/OR an One Time Download link, but can it do both?

Comment: And what is now your question. Your answered yourself.

Comment: [Don't forget to read the API documents :)](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/)

Comment: @Prix, there isn't something like that in the docs.

Comment: @Mindbreaker, the question is there, just read ten times what I've said and asked.

Comment: @user2301842 nope there is not, but you can make a direct link and you can update it with other options with what documents show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate one time direct download link, simply because one time download link is only redirecting to direct download link...

After click "Download", you receive 302 HTTP code (redirect) from POST request... So there is GET request to Location header from response, which is direct download link :)